# Drawing in orthograhphic

Tags: technical-drawing

[image]

I need to draw this in orthograhpic views. I'm a bit confused about the weight of lines I should use to draw. Like ,for the pat (I pointed the arrow at) you can see it's sticking out a bit, would I use just a regular weight line or what?

Also. We've been given some dimensions like 30mm and 70mm. And the thing also says the drawings need to be done on a 1:1 scale. What does this mean? DOes this mean I need to draw exactly at 30mm and 70mm, not make it bigger ration?

Comment: Scale 1:1 is all dimensions are true ie 70mm is 70mm. Line weights should be the same except for hidden detail. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection

Comment: This being drawn in a CAD program?

Comment: @SolarMike The site works best if you put answers in answers and not in comments. I think your answer is correct BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You Should use a regular line with HB pencil to draw that pointed part (it's important its the part that popping out can be seen in front view but you can't see that in side view, but you can see the line).
1:1 Scale shows that you have to make the diagram in 30mm and 70mm only you cant make it 60mm and 140mm as that would be changed to 2:1. Usually 1:1 implies that use the dimensions exactly given in the question you can't make it bigger or smaller.

Comment: Never used anything as soft as HB... clarity of line was 2H...

Comment: 2B or not 2B, ... Not 2B, I guess. It's too soft.